# mysql query group by where column distinct

Tags: mysql

Hey all I have the following Query:

```
SELECT count(e.id), count(c.id), e.Nid
  FROM tbl1 e
  LEFT JOIN tbl2 c
  ON e.Uid = c.Uid
  where e.at > '".$from."'
  AND e.at < '".$to."'
  GROUP BY e.Nid
```

So I have two tables, one for when a user comes onto my site and another for when he makes an account (its my own site traffic monitor). Nid is user agent based on browser.

So this tells me how many ppl came on and how many created accounts by browser type. 
Now my problem is I want to add a clause such as WHERE e.IP is unique.

Please can someone point me in the right direction with this, I'm kinda new to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.IP), count(e.id), count(c.id), e.Nid
FROM tbl1 e
LEFT JOIN tbl2 c
ON e.Uid = c.Uid
where e.at > '".$from."'
AND e.at < '".$to."'
GROUP BY e.Nid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(e.IP), count(e.id), count(c.id), e.Nid
FROM tbl1 e
LEFT JOIN tbl2 c
ON e.Uid = c.Uid
where e.at > '".$from."'
AND e.at < '".$to."'
GROUP BY e.Nid
```

You need to use the Distinct Keyword.  As it says, it only selects distinct or unique records for that field.

Answer (score 0):

In other words you want to count unique IP adresses in `tbl1`. In that case you will not be able to join `tbl1` with `tbl2` on `Uid` as I presume you can have multiple `Uid`'s for each IP address in `tbl1`.